# Tag merge/synonym proposal: [esc] [speedcontroller]

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-cleanup, tag-synonyms

The tags [esc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esc) (113 questions) and [speedcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speedcontroller) (89 questions) are essentially the same thing, and both poorly named (cryptic or unhyphenated). I propose that they should be merged/synonymized, perhaps to something like [speed-controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed-controller) or [motor-controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motor-controller), but in any case there should not be two tags.

I'm bringing this up on meta because they both have a substantial number of questions, and neither one is a good name for a mere synonym proposal, so it seems worth moderator action. (I have been trying to remove [controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/controller), an ambiguous tag whose own excerpt says it shouldn't be used, and a significant fraction of its uses are about motor controllers.)

Caveats:

- The [speedcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speedcontroller) excerpt claims that it could be used e.g. for devices which control fuel flow to an engine. This seems unlikely to be useful or used.
- It might make sense to make further distinctions:

  - brushless motor controllers vs. brushed motor controllers (we already have [brushed-dc-motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushed-dc-motor) and [brushless-dc-motor](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/brushless-dc-motor), which could be taken as supporting the distinction or as that we should use those tags instead)
  - digital/PWM control vs. various [more specialized/simplified things](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/296059/how-does-this-circuit-control-motor-speed)

  and arguably [esc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esc) might mean one of those, but I don't think it is consistently used that way, and I think there should be a tag that suits all-kinds-of-motor-controllers since they have common elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm inclined to make the tag [motor-controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motor-controller) and merge both [esc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esc) and [speedcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speedcontroller) into it. I'm not sure that the distinction between BLDC and brushed DC motors is useful in the tags, but I'm open to corrections.

Update:

Tags [esc](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/esc), [speedcontroller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speedcontroller), and[speed-controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/speed-controller) have been merged together. They all have synonyms to [motor-controller](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motor-controller).

Comment: When are you planning to implement this?

Comment: @KevinReid Heh... I made the speed-controller tag instead of motor-controller. All finished.

Comment: Ah. Looks good now, and I can get back to fixing [tag:controller]!